# Why does empty @Html.Sitecore().Placeholder("main") generate <div class="row"></div>?

Tags: sxa, placeholders

I am working with SXA  1.8 on Sitecore 9.0 update 2. Since Bootstrap 4 is being selected for the current site, `~/Views/SxaLayout/Bootstrap4Body.cshtml` view is being used. This view has such a code:

```
<main>
    <div id="content" class="@Html.Sxa().GridPlaceholderClasses("main")">
        @Html.Sitecore().Placeholder("main")
    </div>
</main>
```

(*I definitely know that particular view is being used since it hits in debugger*), but having no components assigned into itself, it rendered with:

```
<main>
    <div id="content" class="container">
        <div class="row"></div>
    </div>
</main>
```

Thus there is a question: where does `<div class="row"></div>` come from and should not be it empty?

Comment: What do you have if you remove the placeholder code line and reload?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For Bootstrap 3, I think these were hardcoded on the body view, but for Bootstrap 4, on this item - /sitecore/system/Settings/Feature/Experience Accelerator/Bootstrap 4/Bootstrap 4 Grid Definition
you should see a section that defines the Placeholder Wrapper tag/class

[image]

Comment: That precisely answers the question. Thank you!

Answer (score -2):

Firstly, remove this line and reload:

```
@Html.Sitecore().Placeholder("main")
```

If the **row div** is still there, then remove this piece of code:

```
class="@Html.Sxa().GridPlaceholderClasses("main")"
```

I'm pretty sure that by doing so you will know exactly where this **div row** line is coming from.

After that, it's just a matter of troubleshooting your own code and start isolating the possible origins to figure out the exact source of this weird line.

Comment: That was the first I did, in order to identify that particular line generates div

Comment: And what was the outcome?

Comment: The outcome I initially wrote in my question: placeholder does that! That's why I raised my question - why and how does it